# how to interpret a two-byte value?

Tags: byte

I am trying to read a 2-byte value that is stored lower order byte first. So if the 2 bytes are 10 and 85 in that order (decimal) what is the number they represent? 8510? 851? Or something different?

These values represent the length of an encoded sequence and I need to know the length to properly handle the information it contains. Most only use the first byte and as a decimal number it accurately represents the total number of characters (or bytes) in the sequence... but some use both bytes and I don't understand how to interpret them.

IF anyone can help be with this I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you're referring to is the "endianness" of the two-byte value (also called a WORD). It's generally not considered beneficial to discuss them in terms of decimal values because no, if the bytes are `10` and `85` in decimal, the values would not be any combination of 10/85. Rather, showing them in the hexadecimal values is far more prudent.

```
+----+----+
|0x0a|0x55|
+----+----+
```

To interpret this as **Little Endian**, the value would be `0x550a` (`21770` in decimal). And in **Big Endian** (highest order byte first), the value is `0x0a55` (`2645` decimal).

It's very important, for this reason, to know the endianness of your system and be able to properly handle the two. It is also noteworthy that "Network Byte Order" is Big Endian.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful (and ignorance forgiving) reply. I get the necessity of working in hexadecimal. My source data is a document that I am reading char by char and the language I am using (LiveCode) can convert characters to decimal numbers. I can then convert those numbers to base 16. So, if I have two hex values of C4 and 03 in that order, representing a "word" that is "higher order byte second" or "lowendian" if I understand this, they should be rearranged as "3C4" to convert back to decimal -- with a value of 964... is that correct?

Comment: and just to confirm if the original data was "C4" and "10" then it would be rearranged as "10C4" not "1C4" is that correct? Thanks for your indulgence of a non-programmer trying to make his way in this digital world.